# Blank pages when printing using print media query

Tags: html, css, printing, media-queries, zurb-foundation

I have a Zurb Foundation 5 site and everything is working fine except for the print media css.

When using "Emulate CSS media" in the Element Inspector for Chrome, it looks perfect, but when actually printing, there are several blank pages before and after the actual content. 
I've spent several hours to find the problem, but without any luck so far.

Hopefully someone can help me.
An example page is: http://dev.zwedenweb.com/algemeen/ambassades-consulaten-en-verkeersbureaus/

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,
Jasper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to move the ".hide-for-print" class up to the parent divs.
Thanks to Tim at the Zurb support forum: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/26135-blank-pages-when-printing-using-print-media-query